# Xamarin.Forms: Use of GetMainPage()

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently reading the *navigation* section from [An Introduction to Xamarin.Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#6.navigation). One should use the `GetMainPage()` method. But how should that be used?

The default implementation of the app delegate looks like the following:

*Applicaton Delegate:*

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();

        LoadApplication (new App ());

        return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
    }
}
```

*App:*

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        MainPage = GetMainPage ();
    }

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        var mainNav = new NavigationPage(new ListExample());
        return mainNav;
    }
}
```

I got it managed to use the `GetMainPage()`method instead of getting

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

If I look into the (old?) examples ([example1](http://www.knowing.net/index.php/2014/05/30/using-xamarin-forms-maps-you-have-to-init-first/), [example2](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=N%3AXamarin.Forms)) the app delegate is different and a `CreateViewController()` method is available. In my case it is not!

What is the correct way of loading the root page on to the stack?

Comment: the way you have shown here is correct. It is because Xamarin changed the way applications are initialised. New applications now inherit from `Application`

Comment: @user1: So I don't need `GetMainPage()` anymore? It would be nice if Xamarin would update their documentation ...

Comment: no the documentation is correct. The old examples showing CreateViewController() are not

Comment: @user1: Yeah, but the examples are all using the old system. E.g. the app delegate in the introduction tutorial looks different, `Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize (20)` is deprecated ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `GetMainPage()`; that's just a method *you* create. The way X.Forms works these days is: it exposes a `MainPage` property in the Xamarin.Forms `Application` class. You set this to an instance of a `Page`. How you create that page is up to you. You can either use

`this.MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = ... }`

or you create one file per page (which IMHO is best for maintainability):

`this.MainPage = new MyLoginPage();`

or you use helper methods which create your pages:

`this.MainPage = this.GetMainPage();`

The main page is the first page of your Forms application. You can set the `MainPage` property to a different value to show another page.

Earlier versions of Forms used different approaches and not all samples have been updated yet. Now all platforms only need a call to the Forms `Init()` method and a call to `LoadApplication()` instead of creating a view controller, an activity or a page (WP8).